Small Cap Not Produced for Acutely Accented e Using [T1]fontenc
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin} 
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}
{\scshape{Cure}}\\[5pt]

{\scshape{Cur{\'{e}}}}
\end{document}

which produces

QUESTION: Why, when invoking \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} does the acute accent cause small caps to fail for the accented e; however, if I remove the accent, everything seems fine.
Remark: If I replace \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} with \usepackage{fontenc}, everything compiles as expected. I am using the cabin font.

note \scshape{Cure} should be \scshape Cure as \scshape doesn't take an argument (although that makes no difference to your question) also \usepackage{fontenc}, does nothing at all which explains your last remark.

@DavidCarlisle \scshape would put anything which follows in small caps. I often write {\scshape{}} for it has been my experience that any lesser amount of braces does not restrict the small caps to that only which is desired.

@DavidCarlisle Granted , in the MWE, it would have been more efficient to write it the way you have suggested.

no the outer braces (which I didn't suggest you remove) limit the scope. the inner braces make it look like scshape has an argument, which it doesn't which won't confuse latex but will confuse human readers (including the comment above where you suggest it has any effect at all on the scope of the small caps)


The font has incorrect accented letters but you can force latex to put an accent over an e rather than use the pre-formed e-acute glyph.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin} 
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}
{\scshape Cure}% badness 10000\\[5pt]

\bigskip

{\scshape Cur\'{\relax e}}
\end{document}

the default OT1 encoding has no accented letters so the accent is always placed over a base letter in that case.

There's basically nothing you can do: the font is completely wrong. Here's the font table:

You should clearly see the problem, namely that the lowercase accented letters are not small caps.
A (hackish) workaround is to instruct LaTeX to use OT1 when small caps are used.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin} 
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\AddToHook{cmd/scshape/before}{\fontencoding{OT1}}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Cure}

\textsc{Cur\'{e}}

\textsc{Curé}

\end{document}


Please, note that \scshape is not a command taking an argument.

But why does using fontenc without [T1] render the accented e as a small cap?

@DDS Because in OT1 there is no precomposed accented letter, so the low-level method is used of superimposing the accent to the lowercase e.

@DDS I added a workaround so OT1 is used for small caps.
